# How do I find the limit of the following sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, cauchy-sequences

$a_0$ to $a_5$ are set independently, all positive.

Then let us define the sequence as $a_n=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^6a_{n-i}}{6},\;\forall n\geq6$.

How do I find $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n$?

Or, will it converge at all? Or will it just be exactly the limit value after some $n$?

Comment: From what you said it seems that $a_n$ is constant $\forall n\geq 6$, so it must converge to that same value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**
Note that if
$$x_n = \begin{pmatrix}
a_{n-5}\\
a_{n-4}\\
a_{n-3}\\
a_{n-2}\\
a_{n-1}\\
a_{n}
\end{pmatrix} ; \, \, \, \, \, A = \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1& 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1/6 & 1/6 &1/6 &1/6 &1/6 &1/6
\end{pmatrix},
$$
We have $x_n = Ax_{n-1}$.
You can check that $1$ is the single eigenvalue of $A$ with greatest absolute, and its associated eigenvector is 
$$v = \begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
1\\
1\\
1\\
1
\end{pmatrix}.$$ 
From [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/851507/power-iteration), if $a_0+\dots+a_5 \ne 0$, then $x_n$ converges to a multiple of $v$, say $x_n \rightarrow c v$ for some $c$. This proves that if $a_0+\dots+a_5 \ne 0$, the sequence converges.

To find $c$, keeping in mind  that $w = \frac{1}{21} (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)$ is the left eigenvector associated with eigenvalue $1$, try to show that $$c = w\, x_5,$$
which means $a_n \rightarrow \frac{1}{21} (a_0 + 2a_1+\dots+6a_5)$.